# How do I use this array format?

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays

How do I use this format?

```
var dataSet = [
['Trident', 'Internet Explorer 4.0', 'Win 95+', '4', 'X']

];
```

I want to put my knowledge to this format server side or javascript
thank you

```
public ActionResult GetModuls()
{   
   var model = BLcontext.GetModuls();      
   return Json(new { data = model }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);                       
}
```

Comment: it is array of arrays

Comment: What are you asking exactly? What is the data type?

Comment: What's the return type of `BLcontext.GetModuls()`? Do you want to return JSON in the given format?

Answer (score 0):

1) If you want return JSON - write string or JsonResult in type of Your method.
Like:

```
public JsonResult GetModuls()
{   
   var model = BLcontext.GetModuls();      
   return Json(new { data = model }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);                       
}
```

2) I like use Newtonsoft for work with Json

Answer (score 0):

The question is very unclear. If you are simply trying to convert that to C#:

```
var dataSet = new[] {
    new[] {"Trident", "Internet Explorer 4.0", "Win 95+", "4", "X"}
};
```

If you are trying to serialize/deserialize: use a JSON serializer.

Answer (score 0):

It is basically array of arrays. In c# you have to do something like this:

```
public ActionResult GetModuls()
{
 List<string> words = new List<string> { "Trident", "Internet Explorer 4.0", "Win 95+", "4", "X" };
 List<string> words2 = new List<string> { "MVC", "C#", "LINQ" };
 List<List<string>> listofLists = new List<List<string>> { words,words2 };
 return Json(new { data = listofLists }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I am using List of Lists, you can use Array of Array but it will be converted to array in json.